# Creating a map function to iterate over an API request

Tags: r, purrr, httr

First, here is a `dput` of the data:

```
df <- structure(list(Id = 111323317:111323326, TypeId = c(37L, 
37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L), PlayerId = c(458228L, 
458228L, 458228L, 458228L, 458228L, 458228L, 458228L, 458228L, 
458228L, 458228L), TeamId = c(1866215L, 1866214L, 1866215L, 
1866215L, 1866215L, 1866215L, 1866214L, 1866215L, 1866215L, 1866215L
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Next we turn the data into their own values:

```
Ids <- df$Id
TypeIds <- df$TypeId
PlayerIds <- df$PlayerId
TeamIds <- df$TeamId
```

Next we create the body of data for part of the API call, referencing the above values:

```
data_players = paste0(' { "Context": { "TypeId": "', TypeIds, '" }, "responses": [ { "type": "Players", "PlayerId": "', PlayerIds, '", "TeamId": "', TeamIds, '" } ] } ')
```

Then we use `Ids` to create a string of URLs to call:

```
api_urls <- sprintf('https://api.sports.com/players/%s/stats', Ids)
```

And then, finally, we have the API call itself (this is not the actual URL, for obvious reasons I can't share that):

```
get_data <- POST(api_urls[1], add_headers(.headers=headers_upsert), body = data_players)
```

Obviously, the above example will only use the first value of the `api_urls` string. What I'm looking to do is create a `map` function that will iterate by using both the data from `data_players` and `api_urls`.

What is the most effective way to do this?

Comment: If I understood you question, you're looking for the `purrr::map2_` family of functions.

Comment: Can you show me what you mean? Like contextualized around my data/question? That's how I best learn

Comment: I did it below :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to iterate on both values, right?

To do so you need to use the `purrr::map2_` family of functions, your code would be something like that...

```
get_data <- purrr::map2(
    .x = api_urls, 
    .y = data_players, 
     ~POST(.x, add_headers(.headers=headers_upsert), body = .y))
```

You would use `.y` and `.x` to identify your vectors, and `purrr` would do the rest of the work. It would iterate simultaneously over your vectors and return a list with the result of your operation.

If you don't want a list, instead you want a `data.frame`, for example, you would change the `map2_` flavour. There are a few options like `map2_dbl` (for doubles), `map2_chr` (for character vectors), map2_dfr (for data frame rows).

You might the function documentation [here](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map2.html)